# Inconsistent behavior of `astimezone` and `replace` in python

Tags: python, timezone

I'm using `aztimezone` to localize a given date. I know the using `replace` to change `tzinfo` only changes timezone and does not affect the overall date and time, but I expect that the result of both `aztimezone` and `replace` have same timezones.

PoC:

```
 logger.error(list(payments)[-1].created_time)
 logger.error(list(payments[-1].created_time.astimezone(timezone.get_default_timezone()))
 logger.error(list(payment[-1].created_time.replace(tzinfo=timezone.get_default_timezone()))
```

Output:

```
2017-06-24 20:11:10.130427+00:00
2017-06-25 00:41:10.130427+04:30
2017-06-24 20:11:10.130427+03:26
```

As you see, offset of `astimezone` is `4:30` but offset of `replace` is `03:26`.
How is this possible if both are using default timezone?

Comment: Check if the problem is astimezone is changing the date and time values but replace not, so the output is different https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace

Comment: @Rendrum `astimezone` does change the date and time because it's localizing the time with respect to the given timezone. The question is, `replace` is also changing the timezone(without localizing date and time) to that given timezone and they both has been given the same timezone as argument, but independent of the date and time, the results have different timezones. Why is that?

Comment: Try this: tz = timezone.get_default_timezone(), then use tz as parameter instead of calling get_default_timezone, also check payments[-1], and payment[-1] and are the same, first assign it to a variable, then test what could be wrong

Comment: @Rendrum it didn't work